# Horn Clause to prolog

Tags: prolog

At the needs of my HW at uni I need to transform some Horn clauses to Prolog but I cannot figure out how to do it. I found out some guides but they describe how to do it with only one fact. So can you give me a brief example on how to do it?

Eg John is beautiful and rich

we can transform it at: not (Beautiful(John)) ^ not(Rich(John)) which is a Horn clause right? So how this can be translated it Prolog?

another example Everyone loves somebody. Horn clause: ∀X∃YLoves(X,Y) how can this be implemented in Prolog?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question you have

```
john :- beautiful, rich.
```

Or having something like:

```
beautiful(john).
rich(john).
```

with the query:

```
beautiful(X),rich(X).
```

Basically every rule in prolog is a horn clause.
By definition, a Logic Program is a program, comprising of Horn clauses.
In prolog when you have a rule that is declared as:

```
a1(X):-a2(X),a3(X),...,an(X)
```

is a horn clause because it is translated as:

```
a1 or not a2 or not a3 or ... or not an
```

So for your second question:
In prolog the universal quantifier is implied when you define a rule so it does
not affect the prolog clause.
So you need to negate your sentence so you can transform the existential quantifier
to a universal one.
So, you have:

```
 ∀X∃YLoves(X,Y)
```

then you negate:

```
 ∀X ∀Y false <- Loves(X,Y))
```

which translates into:

```
:- loves(X,Y).
```

Comment: In prolog, predicates must start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Note that you are proving a weaker sentence. When you negate the query `∀X∀Y False <- Loves(X,Y)`, you get `∃X∃Y Loves(X,Y)` rather than `∀X∃Y Loves(X,Y)`. In general, you can only verify ∃-quantified sentences in Prolog, since having a ∀ quantifier in the sentence would mean you need to include an ∃ quantifier in the query (the negated form) somehow (there is no syntax for this in Prolog) or that you need to skolemnize the ∃-quantified variable by turning `∀X∃Y Loves(X,Y)` into `∀X Loves(X,F(X))`; a function needs to be rewritten as `∀X∃Y Loves(X,Y) <- F(X,Y)` in Prolog, so this doesn't help.